# Datepicker(jQuery) not loading on loading specific javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a peculiar problem.

The datepicker does not work when I load a particular javascript function.

Code: Datepicker

```
$(function() {
    $('input.datepicker').datepicker();
    });

    $(function () {
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
    });
    $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    var a = $("#txtTo").datepicker('getDate').getTime();
    b = $("#txtFrom").datepicker('getDate').getTime();
    c = (a - b) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    $("#rem").val(c);
            }
    });     
});
```

Javascript Function(this executes onLoad)

```
init();
var a;
function init(){
var db = openDatabase('CBDB', '1.0', 'mySpecialDatabaseThatWontWork',10*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user',[], function (tx, results) {
        var rows = results.rows;
        for (var index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            var x = rows.item(index);
            a = results.rows.item(index).empid;
        }
        next();
    });});              
}   
function next(){
var db = openDatabase('CBDB', '1.0', 'mySpecialDatabaseThatWontWork',10*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    console.log("global"+a);
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM login WHERE manager=?',[a], function (tx, results) {
        var rows = results.rows;
        var msg=" ";
        for (var index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            msg +="<option>"+results.rows.item(index).name+","+results.rows.item(index).empid+"</option>"
        }
        var total= "<div class=\"widh1\"><div style=\"text-align: left;\" class=\"margn1\"><p class=\"dateText\">Employee</p><div class=\"selectParent\"><select id=\"type\" class=\"apply1Text\">"+msg+"</select></div></div></div>";
        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  total;
    });});
}
```

I'm not able to spot the mistake. Also the javascript function loads after the HTML content is loaded on to the page.

Comment: any error in console.log?

Comment: console does not show any error

Comment: which script that you load will cause datepicker to malfunction? there might had possible conflict of class name between plugin, try change to another class name and see if it works

Comment: the problem is that the queryselector is replacing the div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the queryselector was replacing the the entire . I changed it to getElementById. Now its working fine.